# Flask - show all data form Mongodb in html template

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am using MongoDB as a database. I want to show all my data in the HTML template
python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'flask_assignment'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://username:password@ds131698.mlab.com:31698/db_name'
mongo = PyMongo(app)
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    emp_list = mongo.db.employee_entry.find()
    return render_template('index.html', emp_list = emp_list)
app.run(debug=True)
```

my HTML code:

```
{% for emp in emp_list %}
<tr>
   <td>{{ emp['name'] }}</td>
   <td>{{ emp['password'] }}</td>
   <td>{{ emp['email'] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

when I ran the server it shows me nothing blank page...

Comment: because you're giving it blank data and there is nothing else visible in your html.

Comment: What should I do

Comment: make sure there is data to display. read pymongo docs and see what the right way to get 1 entry from the db is.

Comment: as well, make sure there is stuff in the db

Comment: i want all data not particular data

Comment: I'm not familiar with pymongo. Check if there is a find_all method. I don't know what `find()` will return if you don't specify a parameter. Read the docs, they'll be more helpful than me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is that the emp_list is very large, and it takes a long time to insert it in the template, see the page won't be shown.

You can limit the data to for example 10 documents, using:

```
emp_list = mongo.db.employee_entry.find().limit(10)
```

and see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm sorry for that msg earlier

*try this:*

```
{% for key,value in emp_list %}
<tr>
   <th scope="row">{{loop.index}}</th>
   <td>{{value}}</td>
   <td>{{value}}</td>
   <td>{{value}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

*where loop.index is used for incrementing you can search it's use*

I am 100% sure that just pasting it without editing it will not work.

But what i am actually trying to say is try using `key,value` function of **for loops** in python(jinja2)

*try edit this so that it can fit in your code*